plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '{agpVersion}', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources
i. have error in my project after update to flutter 3.19.0
 <app project>/android/settings.gradle' line: 22
this line
'id "com.android.application" version "{agpVersion}" apply false`
this my android/settings.gradle
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }()
    // settings.ext.flutterSdkPath = flutterSdkPath()

    includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "{agpVersion}" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "{kotlinVersion}" apply false
}


include ":app"

// apply from: "${settings.ext.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/app_plugin_loader.gradle"

please help me how to fix this

Replce with verion as below with
key agpVersion and kotlinVersion
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
     id "com.android.application" version "8.4.0" apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.4.0" apply false

}

